# Circular Image Drawn in CGRect Has white Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, cgrect

In my app, I build a PDF, and as part of the PDF, the user chooses an image. The app then does a circular crop of the image, and draws it on a PDF. The issue I am facing is that for some reason, it keeps a white background around the sides. How can this be fixed?

```
UIImage * demoImage = self.imageCopy;
    
    NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(demoImage, 1.0);
    CGDataProviderRef dp = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(( CFDataRef)jpegData);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dp, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    
    [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(513, 319, 135, 135)];
```

[image]

Comment: JPG format does not support transparency.

Comment: @DonMag Wow, I feel stupid

Comment: DonMag, you should post your comment as an answer, and include the solution of saving the image as a PNG with alpha.